# How to validate a user request from iPhone is an authenticated Facebook user?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby, facebook

I'd like to build a web application which allow iPhone users to save a short memo as a todo list on the web server. The user must logon on Facebook on the iPhone before submitting a memo.

On the server side, how can I tell whether the iPhone user has logon on Facebook or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a native app, FBConnect can be used to establish trust between the app and Facebook.  (FBConnect calls an fbDidLogin delegate method).

It's up to you to establish trust between your iPhone app and your web service, but once you have, the app can report the FB login state along with it's requests.

Comment: Any suggestion on _trust between iPhone app and web service_?

Comment: A common low-stakes method is to use a shared secret between the app and the web service.  The app uses the secret to generate a signature for it's requests, and includes the signature as a request parameter.  The web server tries to generate same signature with the request and the shared secret.  If the signature matches, then the request is trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just building a [web application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/), I don't understand why it would be different then building a normal web application that uses fbconnect and graph api. You just happen to design it to fit a mobile browser. There's a section on authentication.

Comment: Hope that the user does not need to sign on twice (iPhone and web app).